# Need to replace special character in Impala

Tags: impala

I want to replace only specific list  of special character in impala. other than list of character all other character should remain same.
Only below list should be replace.

```
<
>
:
"
/
\
|
?
*
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `regexp_replace(data_col,'[|?*]','')`. This will replace all symbols mentioned inside `[]` with empty space `''`.

Add whatever symbols you want in the list.

[image]